# How to check JSONB has a field in root?

Tags: postgresql

I try this:

```
select * from "User" where "partnerData" -> 'name' != NULL
```

`partnerData` is a JSONB. I would see those rows, does not have the `name` field in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<>` (or `!=` or any other operator) to check for NULL values, you need to use `IS NULL`. Using `->` also returns a `jsonb` value which might be the literal `null` not the SQL `NULL` value. So you should use `->>` to return a text value (which would then be a SQL NULL)

```
select * 
from "User" 
where "partnerData" ->> 'name' IS NULL
```

Note that this doesn't distinguish between a JSON value that contains the key  `name` but with a value of NULL and a JSON value that does not contain the key at all.

If you only want to check if the key exists (regardless of the value - even if it's a JSON null), use the `?` operator.

```
where "partnerData" ? 'name'
```